# "error: 'x' does not a name type" en un archivo de cabecera

Tags: c++, compilador

Estoy tratando de hacer un archivo de cabecera con una estructura **struct** que contiene 3 variables
y de ella crear un array de estructuras

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H

struct data 
{
    int  number;
    char letter;
    char binary[8];
};

data ascii[3];

//32 = Spc
ascii[0].number =  32;
ascii[0].letter = ' ';
ascii[0].binary = "00100000";

//33 = !
ascii[1].number = 33;
ascii[1].letter = '!';
ascii[1].binary = "00100001";

//34 = "
ascii[2].number = 34;
ascii[2].letter = '"'
ascii[2].binary = "00100010";

#endif
```

El problema es que cuando trato de incluirlo en el main y compilarlo con **g++**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "prueba.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << ascii[2].number << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Al tratar de compilar aparece `error: 'ascii' does not name a type` en cada línea de la cabecera en la que defino los elementos de la estructura `ascii`.

**¿Por qué no encuentra** `ascii`**?**

**¿Qué puedo probar para que compile?**

**Nota:**

*Ya trate de declarar* `data` *antes de usarla y definirla al final*

*También trate de hacer lo mismo con*  `ascii` *, pero hace que el compilador la confunda con otra definición*

Comment: Haz intentado declarando la variable extern data ascii[3];? Utilizando extern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo para assignar los valores a `ascii` es incorecto. Recuerda que C++ no es un lenguaje de scripting, tu codigo no se ejecuta de arriba a abajo. Tus instrucciones tienen que estar adentro de funciones, entonces tienes que poner el codigo en el que lo asignas dentro de el main.

Solo como una nota, la forma en la que estas asingando los `binary` es incorrecto. Primero, no le das el espacio adicional para el `\0` al final, y segundo, no se pueden copiar de esa manera, tienes que usar `strcpy`

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H

struct data 
{
    int  number;
    char letter;
    char binary[9];
};


#endif
```

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "prueba.h"

int main()
{
    data ascii[3];
    
    //32 = Spc
    ascii[0].number =  32;
    ascii[0].letter = ' ';
    strcpy(ascii[0].binary, "00100000");
    
    //33 = !
    ascii[1].number = 33;
    ascii[1].letter = '!';
    strcpy(ascii[1].binary, "00100001");
    
    //34 = "
    ascii[2].number = 34;
    ascii[2].letter = '"';
    strcpy(ascii[2].binary, "00100010");
    std::cout << ascii[2].number << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Si quieres hacerlo fuera del main, puedes construirlo con un initializer list:

```cpp
data ascii[3] = {
    {32, ' ', "00100000"},
    {33, '!', "00100001"},
    {34, '"', "00100010"}
};
```